# Google maps giving security warning in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps

I am doing something like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript"src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?sensor=false&key=my_key">         </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">google.load("maps","2.x");</script>
```

but it gives me a alert saying "this site needs a diff api key", if i make https as http, it works fine but i get security warning in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Google's FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#ssl), you can only use the outdated 2.0 API via HTTPS if you buy the business version of Google Maps. Use the 3.0 API instead.